# Creating a tree structure with a logging dictionary

Tags: python, logging, graphviz, plotly, functools

I have a DF that I'd like to create a tree structure with. My spreadsheet looks like this:

Regional Exposure.750013 | Not Classified.18500016 | Country Exposure (Equity).750015   | Country Exposure (Equity) to Yugoslavia.18750254

Regional Exposure.750013 | Africa.18500008 | Country Exposure (Equity).750015 | Country Exposure (Equity) to South Africa.18750255

Regional Exposure.750013 | Africa.18500008 | Country Exposure (Equity).750015 | Country Exposure (Equity) to Zambia.18750256

Regional Exposure.750013 | Africa.18500008 | Country Exposure (Equity).750015 | Country Exposure (Equity) to Zaire.18750257

... and so on.

I've been able to create a class hierarchy using super(). I'd like to create a diamond tree structure that incorporates left to right parent to child node relationships. For example, in row one, A is the parent of B, B is the parent of C, C is the parent of D.

Does anyone know how to use the LoggingDict to create the tree structure for the whole dataframe? (30,000+ rows)

Thanks,
Nazar

EDIT: We're trying to rebuild this tree that was not created correctly as an array. We've been able to create the super class but having trouble plotting it on a graph

our code for creating the dictionary:

```
import collections
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level='INFO')




class LoggingDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value): 
        class LoggingOD(LoggingDict, collections.OrderedDict):
            pass

import pandas as pd
bdh=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\nkurdob\\Documents\\bdh2.csv')
ld = LoggingDict(bdh)
```

We're hoping to use GraphViz to plot these relationships as a tree. We may not have needed to create a superclass.

Comment: Wait, why do you want a *class hierarchy*?

Comment: We're explaining a portfolio accounting table

Comment: It's not obvious why you need a class hierarchy.

Comment: There are 37,000 rows and it's a diamond tree structure

Comment: Yeah, so? You only really need one class to implement a tree: `Node` but maybe I am not understanding you. You should probably give an example of what you mean.

Comment: No. *Edit your question to add details* Do you really expect people to want to read all of that in a comment?

Comment: My bad, did not know the formatting would be like that. One sec

Comment: In any event, this does nothing to explain why you need a class hierarchy with `super` to make a tree.

Comment: We're noobs, sorry

Comment: Look, again, you need to give more details. What super class? Why do you need inheritance? Does it have something to do with `graphviz`? You need to add details because we cannot know what is in your head and in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Edited to add the code